# C++ Vector/list of priority queues?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector, priority-queue

Why wouldn't C++ allow something like that ?

I need to have multiple priority queues, the number of which would be determined at run time.

This fails to compile

`std::vector<std::priorityqueue<Class A>>`.

Is there a better approach ?

Comment: With what error does it fail to compile... ? How exactly are you using it in your code?

Comment: OK, i might have posted this in haste. Netbeans complained (red line) as i wrote the code ? I thought this might be illegal, is it not ?

Comment: @cyrux: No, why should this be illegal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine. Just the syntax should be:

```
std::vector<std::priority_queue<A> >
```

(note the space (" ") near the end.

Comment: This is only needed if you have a crappy compiler not able to differenciate the operator `>>` and ends of cascaded templates (e.g. MSVC 6.0). This should be no problem for any decent C++ compiler nowadays.

Comment: Oh, so it was treating `>>` as right shift, wow. 
I have Netbeans on linux btw

Comment: @jde: The C++03 language simply doesn't support this, only C++0x will fix it.

Comment: @jdehaan: Wrong. Any strictly C++03 compliant compiler won't accept this.

Comment: Thanks Georg, Axel, I thought it was only a matter of compilers. Good to know that the new C++ standard enforces this to work. Looked to me the compilers got better at parsing.

Answer (score 6):

The correct code would be:

```
std::vector<std::priority_queue<A> >
```

Note that `Class` does not belong next to `A`, `priority_queue` has an underscore in it, and there is a space required between the two right angle brackets (`>>` is parsed as a right shift operator).

This also requires that `A` is less-than comparable (if it is not, then you must provide a comparison function to be used by the priority queue).

Comment: i know about the class and the underscore thing. 
didnt know about the space thing. Probably why it was acting up.

Comment: `std::priority_queue<Block_Details>* free_list; `
is this legal ?

Comment: @cyrux:  Yes, but why do you want a pointer to `priority_queue`?

Comment: Coming to think about it , i dont think arrays of queues are possible. Arrays are supposed to have starting and ending addresses and queues are supposed to grow. this would make it illegal ?

Comment: @cyrux:  Do you know what `vector` and `priority_queue` are and how they function?  If not, you might consult your C++ book or Google (they are well documented in the SGI STL documentation).

Comment: what part of my comment didnt make sense ?

Comment: @cyrux, Objects you create with `new` or `new[]` do not change at runtime.  A `vector` has a pointer to a chunk of memory which (perhaps) changes in size with the size of the array.  The `vector` is storing just the pointer, and the size of a pointer doesn't change at runtime, so the object doesn't change size.  So yes, an array of `priority_queue`s is legal and valid, but you're probably better off using a `vector` or `list` anyway.